# Image randomly corrupt (but load after refresh) and show "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html"

Tags: php, html, image, .htaccess

I am currently working on a simple php website

The problem is , the images in my whole web site(happens in all php files) randomly corrupt and show the error
**Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html**, however, if I try to refresh the page several times. The image can be loaded again and the error is gone.

I have checked all img path and the image is exist. Also, I checked there is no `img src=""` in my file. Is it due to server setting? I check .htaccess file and it is blank. How to fix the problem ? Thanks

**Chrome web developer:**

```
Request URL:http://goodbyedear.com.hk/images/index_48.jpg
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:zh-TW,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:PHPSESSID=ee5297bd4973576b6a318cd9a33c4151; aaaaaaa=96b0422aaaaaaaa_96b0422a
Host:goodbyedear.com.hk
If-Modified-Since:Mon, 21 Oct 2013 17:59:24 GMT
Referer:http://goodbyedear.com.hk/index.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Close
Content-Length:144
Expires:Sat, 6 May 1995 12:00:00 GMT
P3P:CP=NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM
Pragma:no-cache
```

**My code (for reference):**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('db_connect.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>首頁</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <?php require_once ('header.php'); ?>
    <div id="center">
        <img id="slider" src="images/index_17.jpg" />
        <div id="subGroup">
            <div class="sub">
                <img class="subLeft" src="images/index_18.jpg" />
                <img class="subTopRight" src="images/index_19.jpg" />
                <div class="subBottomRight">作為全港第一間成立的寵物火化殯儀公司，其心路歷程盡在此。<a class="viewAll" href="intro.php">View All</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sub" >
                <img class="subLeft" src="images/index_21.jpg" />
                <img class="subTopRight" src="images/index_22.jpg" />
                <div class="subBottomRight">讓您了解詳細的服務流程, 令您更安心... <a class="viewAll" href="service.php">View All</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sub">
                <img class="subLeft" src="images/index_28.jpg" />
                <img class="subTopRight" src="images/index_29.jpg" />
                <div class="subBottomRight">我們了解每隻寵物在主人心目中都是獨一無二，所以提供各種不同的紀念品，讓客人選擇製作獨一無二的紀念品，讓您的寵兒以另一型式留在主人身邊。<a class="viewAll" href="souvenir.php">View All</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sub">
                <img class="subLeft" src="images/index_30.jpg" />
                <img class="subTopRight" src="images/index_31.jpg" />
                <div class="subBottomRight">感謝您對我們的任何意見，歡迎留言給我們！<a class="viewAll" href="board.php">View All</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="latestNews">
            <img id="latestTitle" src="images/index_23.jpg" />
            <img id="latestLeft" src="images/index_25.gif" />
            <div id="latestContent">
                <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM pet_news LIMIT 6";
                $result = $dbh->query($sql);
                if ($result->rowCount() == 0) {
                    echo "<p>沒有最新消息</p>";
                } else {
                    foreach ($result->fetchAll() as $key => $row) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="newsItem">
                        <div class="newsBoxTitle"><?php echo $row["title"];?></div>
                        <div class="newsBoxDate"><?php echo $row["date"];?></div>
                        <div class="newsBoxContent"><?php echo mb_substr($row["content"],0,30,"UTF-8")."......";?></div>
                        <a class="newsLink" href="news.php?page=1#news<?php echo ($key + 1);?>">詳情</a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                }
                $dbh = null;
                ?>
            </div>
            <img id="latestBottom" src="images/index_36.gif" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php require_once ('footer.php'); ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are facing is caused (most probably) by this line of your httpd.conf:

```
#LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
```

You must uncomment it so that it looks like (restart apache after that) this:

```
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
```

This module is responsible for providing mime types (Content-Type headers) to your HTTP responces. Without it (Content-Type header) your browser must perform so called type sniffing which is roughy described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for IE (but may look alike for other browsers)

Another reason (if you have this module working) is that you lack **mime.types** file or it does not contain mime types for files that you are trying to serve.

See below - on the left - this is how you are serving your images and on the right is how it should look like:

[image]

Left - mod_mime commented out

Right - mod_mime uncommented

Answer (score 3):

#### What I did

I opened an image in new tab. Opened developer tools, navigated to Network tab and checked 'preserve log upon navigation'.

#### Results

Image loaded normally, but after two or five reloads, I received `text/html` content, which automatically reloaded a new `text/html` and then finally reloaded automatically to `image/jpeg`. That's why you see normal image if opened in new tab, and `text/html` when loading through HTML. Obviously, source of `<img/>` can't be `text/html`, so it doesn't reload automatically, as it happens in directly opened image in new tab.
[image]
The one with red outline is the first `text/html` and the blue arrows are the automatic reload indicators.

#### Logs

Here is the log of four requests, normal image, first html, second html and final image - **http://pastebin.com/L5wKurZp**

#### Reasons

I think it a problem in your web server.

#### Solutions

I have no idea, but you can try adding this lines to your `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType image/webp        webp
    AddType image/jpeg        jpg jpeg
    AddType image/webp        webp
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I found the problem not only happens in jpg but also gif and css

Comment: This is obviously caused by the web server. Are you using a free web hosting? Because I've experienced issues like this only on free hostings

Comment: Thanks. I believe the problem is caused by the hosting too. As my code is working well on own built Apache server. I just wonder whether I can fix it through adding some settings in htaccess. I tried addType but that does not work

Comment: No, the HTML reply is too complex to be the result of a missing MIME setting. This is something *actively* running on the server. `mod_rewrite`, but possibly even something more, on a load balancer of some kind. Adding an answer...

Answer (score 1):

The image is not "corrupt". Rather, you get a HTML file that tries to reload the image itself; and this kind of thing is not supported by all browsers, since JS redirect is not a standard HTTP redirect. This is the anomalous contents:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Expires: Sat, 6 May 1995 12:00:00 GMT
P3P: CP=NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 144
Connection: Close

<html><body><script>document.cookie='jjjjjjj=8eb87ff1jjjjjjj_8eb87ff1; path=/';window.location.href=window.location.href;</script></body></html>
```

What could causing this? Well, of course you are **not** getting the image; the request does not "land" on the image, **it is being intercepted** - check the settings for `mod_rewrite`. The system is apparently trying to set a cookie and redirecting, but it is doing so in Javascript. You ought to do this server-side in PHP and only send Cookie headers and a 302 Redirect:

```
<?php
    setcookie('jjjjjjj', '8eb87ff1jjjjjjj_8eb87ff1');
    header("Location: {$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");
    exit();
?>
```

I also got, for the same URL, a message saying that **the image is not there**. Apparently there is more than one server answering requests. When the request hits a "good" server you get the image, otherwise you get a HTML "please retry" or an outright error.

```
HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Date: Sat, 16 Nov 2013 22:46:48 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 389
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>406 Not Acceptable</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Acceptable</h1>
<p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource /images/index_48.jpg could not be found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```