# The graphic in the website is broken occasionly

Tags: php, html, css, image, .htaccess

I am currently working on a simple php website

The problem is , the images in my whole web site(happens in all php files) randomly corrupt and show the error
**Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html**, however, if I try to refresh the page several times. The image can be loaded again and the error is gone.

I have checked all img path and the image is exist. Also, I checked there is no `img src=""` in my file. Is it due to server setting? I check .htaccess file and it is blank. How to fix the problem ? Thanks

Comment: Please don't duplicate post; this is a duplicate of your post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827572/image-randomly-corrupt-but-load-after-refresh-and-show-resource-interpreted-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible reason for this could be an intermittent server error, which serves an error page instead of the image resource.

Apache's `access.log` will tell you which response code the images were sent with (200 means "ok"). `error.log` will tell you the exact error message if you find an error.

This could also be the intermittent hick-up of a company or ISP proxy server.

Comment: Thanks for your helping . I can't find access.log in the ftp server. And there is error.log, But there is no error record about this problem.

Comment: I also found that not only image (gif, jpg) but also css are Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

Comment: Can you see in Chrome's dev tool what the response body contains?